# jquery scrollto not working on all links

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, href, move

on this page: http://klanten.noxxie.nl/msbc/news.php?id=1
I have a problem getting jquery to work with all the links

only when you click the first hyper link "reageer op deze reactie"
you will be moved to the bottom to to form,

though the other ones are not responding, any idea what is causing this?
link to jquery: http://klanten.noxxie.nl/msbc/js/anchor-scroll/jquery.anchorScroll.js
how its activated with jquery: klanten.noxxie.nl/msbc/js/custom.js (at the bottom)

anybody knows why jquery isnt recognizing them all?

Comment: Consider giving us a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/)? This not only helps us help you, but also helps everyone who stumbles on this question later. Everyone wins!

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the scroll function to a class instead of an id

(custom.js(564): $("#movescroll").anchorScroll();

another thing, id's should be unique.

Comment: Patrick, can you confirm the answer. I notice that you fixed it according to my answer.

grtz Peter